# Why doesn't the "Releases" menu appear?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps. I'm creating a CI/CD pipeline for a project. In the videos I watch there is a "Releases" menu used to configure the CD. However, in my profile, "Releases" does not appear.

[image: Menus]

What I'm not understanding? Has the website interface changed?

It's a simple question, but I can't continue my work.

Comment: You probably don't have access to the releases section. However, "releases" is largely deprecated in favor of YAML pipelines, so you should probably start out with YAML anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to create a pipeline for a course project. Videos must be out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to re-enable it from organization settings (ask an admin for it)

then, under Pipelines > Settings, disable those 2 options like so :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntki2.png)

Comment: Both of these options seem enabled to me. I use a free account for studies. How can I contact someone to help me with this?

Comment: thanks I am looking for solution from yesterday because all tutorial video showing that option and i could not find

Answer (score 1):

You have to go the Organization level and then go to the Project Settings > Pipelines > Settings, and there you can enable the creation of the releases Menu:

[image: Enable the releases menu]